# Can someone help explain how to identify if a system of equation is solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain to me how they can come to the conclusion that this is solvable if they look at it? I'm still confused since only variables are being used and I'm getting really confused.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkrwY.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of a rank of a matrix? Because the rank of the matrix with columns $(1,2,1),(1,0,2), (1,1,0)$ is $3$. This means that those three vectors span the whole $\mathbb R^3$ and any vector can be expressed as a linear combination of those three.